# Bracket right after return statement

Tags: javascript

```
function transpose(data) {
    return data.replace(/[abc]/ig, function(d) {
        return {
            'a': '1',
            'b': '2'
        }[d];
    });
}
```

I am having a little trouble making sense of the return part of this function.

If I am understanding this correctly, return gives back an object literal. (Please correct me if wrong.)

The parameter [d] is being called to access the object literal property? (Is this correct?)

E.g:

```
var x = {'a': '1', 'b': '2'}
return x['a']
```

Comment: yes, your understanding is correct

Comment: and yes, nobody should write functions like this because of how ambiguous it looks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just look at the basics of accessing the property of an object. You have 2 ways (not including ES6 object destructuring):

1. object.property
2. object['property']

So in this case, it's using the square brackets [] property accessor method.

The function is returning the object and accessing the property passed as the d parameter.